# Transform numpy ndarray from a column list to row list

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a ndarray, whose shape is (5,2). How to change it to a row list, instead of a column list.
Here is the code

```
poly
array([['610.0', '1150.0'],
   ['675', '1150'],
   ['675', '1215'],
   ['610', '1215'],
   ['610', '1150']], 
  dtype='|S32')
shape(poly)
 (5,2)
poly.tolist()
 [['610.0', '1150.0'],
 ['675', '1150'],
 ['675', '1215'],
 ['610', '1215'],
 ['610', '1150']]
```

However, what I want to have is

```
 [['610.0', '1150.0'],['675', '1150'],['675', '1215'],['610', '1215'],['610', '1150']]
```

How could I get it?

Comment: That is the difficulty. In my problem, `poly` is an ndarray with the shape (5,2). `poly.tolist()` is a column list of (5,1); each element of the list is a (1,2) array. What I want is a also a list, but a row list whose size is (1, 5). Each element of the list is still (1, 2) array.

Comment: Trying poly.tolist() gives exactly the output you want on my machine. Unsure what you mean by row list / column list?

Comment: Isn't the difference just the special `repr` provided by `ipython` ?

Comment: There's no such thing as row list or column list.  The difference is purely a matter of display formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
the method:

```
ndarray.T
ndarray.transpose()
```

In your case:

```
poly.T
```

or

```
poly.transpose()
```

Use this:

```
import numpy as np
poly=np.array([['610.0', '1150.0'],
   ['675', '1150'],
   ['675', '1215'],
   ['610', '1215'],
   ['610', '1150']], 
  dtype='|S32')

print("poly", poly)

print()

#print(poly.shape())

print("poly.tolist()", poly.tolist())

#print(poly.T)
print()

print("poly.transpose()", poly.transpose())
```

Comment: I tried this method, but what I get is error: `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Comment: In fact, I can use `poly.transpose()`, but what I get is `array([['610.0', '675', '675', '610', '610'],
       ['1150.0', '1150', '1215', '1215', '1150']], 
      dtype='|S32')`, which is not what I need.

Comment: You have only 2 results: 1. [['610.0', '1150.0'],['675', '1150'],['675', '1215'],['610', '1215'],['610', '1150']] or 2. [['610.0','675', '675','610','610'],['1150.0', '1150', '1215','1215', '1150']]. For the first you don't need transpose(), only you need to the second.

Comment: Thank Adolfo for your patience. The two outputs I have seem to be the same, but error occurs when I input to `ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(poly)`. I need to check where is the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that `poly.T` is a property, not a method, so you just need to use `poly.T` instead of `poly.T()`